# Spring Boot+ Azure service Bus

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to wire my spring boot application to Azure Service Bus. When I add the below dependency in the pom.xml file I am getting an error after I build my project.

pom.xml dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>             
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-servicebus-jms</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Exception encountered:

> 12-28-2021 15:28:15.779 EST [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO  c.a.s.k.secrets.SecretAsyncClient - Retrieved secret - npSigningStationBasicAuthPassword
> 12-28-2021 15:28:15.780 EST [main] INFO  c.c.s.e.KeyVaultPropertyInitializer - Getting property from key vault: edocs.exact.target.apigee.apikey
> 12-28-2021 15:28:15.781 EST [main] INFO  c.a.s.k.secrets.SecretAsyncClient - Retrieving secret - npExactTargetApiKey
> 12-28-2021 15:28:15.862 EST [reactor-http-nio-1] INFO  c.a.s.k.secrets.SecretAsyncClient - Retrieved secret - npExactTargetApiKey
> 12-28-2021 15:28:15.878 EST [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.azure.spring.cloudfoundry.environment.VcapResult] to type [java.lang.String]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321)
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194)
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174)

Answer (score 0):

Before adding you need to install Azure Spring Boot Starter for Azure Service Bus JMS dependency with below command:

```
    mvn install
```

Later add the dependency to pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>  
        <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-servicebus-jms</artifactId>  
        <version>3.10.0</version>  
    </dependency>
```

Later add the below dependency to project:

1. [Add dependency to a Gradle project](https://jmaven.com/dependency/azure-spring-boot-starter-for-azure-service-bus-jms/com.azure.spring/azure-spring-boot-starter-servicebus-jms#add-dependency-to-a-gradle-project)
2. [Add dependency to a SBT Scala project](https://jmaven.com/dependency/azure-spring-boot-starter-for-azure-service-bus-jms/com.azure.spring/azure-spring-boot-starter-servicebus-jms#add-dependency-to-a-sbt-scala-project)
3. [Add dependency to a Grape project](https://jmaven.com/dependency/azure-spring-boot-starter-for-azure-service-bus-jms/com.azure.spring/azure-spring-boot-starter-servicebus-jms#add-dependency-to-a-grape-project)